# React-Native: Picker can't select any other item. Error: Actions may not have and undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?

Tags: react-native

I'm learning React Native and I'm stuck on a Picker problem. On clicking it shows up but I can't select anything else other than "Monday". Whenever I do, I get an error

I've tried searching for the problem on the internet and worked with my action creators but nothing seems to work

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Picker, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { employeeUpdate } from '../actions';
import { Card, CardSection, Input, Button } from './common';

class EmployeeCreate extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Card>
                <CardSection>
                    <Input
                        label='Name'
                        placeholder='Jane'
                        value={this.props.name}
                        onChangeText={value => this.props.employeeUpdate({ prop: 'name', value })}
                    />
                </CardSection>

                <CardSection>
                    <Input
                        label='Phone'
                        placeholder='555-555-5555'
                        value={this.props.phone}
                        onChangeText={value => this.props.employeeUpdate({ prop: 'phone', value })}
                    />
                </CardSection>

                <CardSection style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                    <Text style={styles.pickerTextStyle}>Shift</Text>
                    <Picker
                        style={{ alignItems: "center" }}
                        selectedValue={this.props.shift}
                        onValueChange={value => this.props.employeeUpdate({ prop: 'shift', value })}
                    >
                        <Picker.Item label="Monday" value="Monday" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Tuesday" value="Tuesday" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Wednesday" value="Wednesday" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Thursday" value="Thursday" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Friday" value="Friday" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Saturday" value="Saturday" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Sunday" value="Sunday" />
                    </Picker>
                </CardSection>

                <CardSection>
                    <Button>Create</Button>
                </CardSection>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    pickerTextStyle: {
        fontSize: 18,
        paddingLeft: 20
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const { name, phone, shift } = state.employeeForm;

    return { name, phone, shift };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { employeeUpdate })(EmployeeCreate);
```

Here is my EmployeeActions File:

```
import EMPLOYEE_UPDATE from './types'

export const employeeUpdate = ({ prop, value }) => {
    return {
        type: EMPLOYEE_UPDATE,
        payload: { prop, value }
    };
};
```

Here is the EmployeeFormReducer:

```
import EMPLOYEE_UPDATE from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = { name: '', phone: '', shift: '' };

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case EMPLOYEE_UPDATE:
            //action.payload === { prop: 'name', value: 'jane' }
            return { ...state, [action.payload.prop]: action.payload.value };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I expect to select any day as per my choice

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Did some changes in types.js file:

```
export const EMAIL_CHANGED = 'email_changed';
export const PASSWORD_CHANGED = 'password_changed';
export const LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS = 'login_user_success';
export const LOGIN_USER_FAIL = 'login_user_fail';
export const LOGIN_USER = 'login_user';
export const EMPLOYEE_UPDATE = 'employee_update';

export default {
    EMAIL_CHANGED,
    PASSWORD_CHANGED,
    LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_USER_FAIL,
    LOGIN_USER,
    EMPLOYEE_UPDATE
}
```